# ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I realize there are other (preferred) ways of implementing authentication with Azure Active Directory, but is it possible to use the standard **ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider** with **Azure Active Directory** for an **Azure website**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no way to use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider with Azure Active Directory.
. (Period) :)

Why?

ActiveDirectoryMambershipProvider uses [Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM) server and talks to AD over LDAP protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx). Both of which are not supported by Azure AD. The replacement of LDAP in the Cloud is [Azure AD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx).

You can however use the Claims Based Authentication / Authorization model and protect your web site with Azure AD. This will help with Authentication. Authorization - you can use the role based access control and have your Azure AD groups translated into ASP.NET roles.

[Here is pretty long and well described process of how to protect a web site with Azure AD without writing single line of custom code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/04/use-a-microsoft-account-to-create-web-apps-protected-by-azure-ad-with-vs2013-update-3.aspx).